# given a zookeeper server ip:port, how to get the zookeeper structure?

Tags: distributed, apache-zookeeper

given a zookeeper server ip:port, how to get the zookeeper structure?
for example I was told a zookeper service server is 192.1.2.17:2181

I can use ZKcli.sh to login and do some basic stuff. I can use it without problem.
But I want to know how many nodes in this zookeeper setup? Who are those nodes？? what are their status?
How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find some of these commands useful:

http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/trunk/zookeeperAdmin.html#The+Four+Letter+Words

You can run them against the server ip:port you were given, e.g.:

```
echo MNTR | nc 192.1.2.17 2181
```

If you have access to that host, you could just check the configuration that is usually under something like `<zoo install>/conf/zoo.cfg`.